# RAM not clearing, alway in standby

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm having a problem with my ram on windows 7. The ram is clearing or programs are using and dumping it faster than it can clear. I have 8gb of ram I'm only using 4gb and the rest is in Standby. At best time I can get 100mb of free but its mostly at 15mb or less. I suspect a memory leak but I have no way to figure out what program it is. I have not installed any new hardware recently and newly installed programs have bin closed. Does any one have an idea of what is going on and how to fix it?

I'm sorry this is so little information but that is all I have as well.

**Edit:**
I tried RamMap and found out the my "Mapped File" has 3,291,784k ram in standby how do I figure out what program and how do I limit it's ability to set ram in standby?

**Edit:**
I keep getting a problem when I will have 0 free ram and my computer will stop working properly. It will become outrageously slow where it will take 3-4 minutes to start task manager so I can close some programmes. When I free up some ram by closing some programmes every thing runs normally. It does not matter which programs I closes only that I free up some ram. I know a lot of you say it's supposed to be like that and that's how windows works. But its obviously a problem and my computer has never worked that way neither has any of my other computers. I would like to fix this please help me.

Comment: Your memory is suppose to be in `Standby`. Its either active or waiting to be used.  I have 32GB of memory.  4GB is active 15GB is in `Standby` and the rest is either `Zeroed` or `Modified` what you describe isn't an actual problem

Comment: Really because out of all the five computers I have ever had this is the fist time I have had this problem. Now my computer runs slow as poop. Like 1/3 the speed it would normally run when I had 2gb in Free.

Comment: My computers definition of Standby: Memory that contains cached data and code that is not actively in use.

My computers definition of Free: Memory that does not contain any valuable data, and that will be used first when processes, drivers or the operating system need more memory.

I'm not trying to sound like a peace of poo. But if my computer never did it before then why does it do it now. As well as my computer ran faster then than now. So if it was broken then and then and not now how can I brake it in that way. If not and that's how computers are supposed to run how do I fix it?

Comment: It seems to me that it would be a good thing to try and get more ram to be in "Free" than "Standby".

Comment: Unused system memory is useless.  Just because its cached does not mean it cannot be used.

Comment: Most of the people asking about Standby memory simply don't understand how Windows manages memory.[here is a good explaination](http://superuser.com/questions/173838/how-do-i-make-windows-7-less-aggressive-in-caching-memory).  You can always try adjusting your page file.

Comment: But it takes more time for stuff to load. Again I don't mean to sound like some one who is not listening. But I have had problems when my ram would be all in "Standby" and my computer would it gets really hot and loads really slowly. Sounds will became wash bored like not smooth. The only way I could fix this is buy cleaning up my ram. By taking out a stick of ram starting my computer and turning it on and off and repeat for both stick. Then I would be back to my normal 2-3gb "Free" ram. That is why I suspect a memory leak or faulty stick of ram. All cpu and used ram were normal.

Comment: @Spik330 Since it is clear by now that 'standby' is not the issue, I suggest you rewrite your question to what it really is (slow operation) and leave out the assumption about standby memory (other then a side remark like "At first I thought it had to do with standby memory"). And I'm afraid your going to have to post more information about that computer and its processes for anyone to make meaningful suggestions.

Comment: [The same thing confuses newcomers to Linux.](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: @bwDraco except in Linux it works flawlessly whereas in Windows it rarely does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Large standby values are fantastic. This means the data are cached by superfetch service and are not **actively being** used. These are still left in physical ram but **will be repurposed first by the memory manager** (either returned to the active list or zeroed out and reused) **if something needs physical ram** for active pages. **Standby pages are essentially cache – it’s better to have infrequently used data kept in RAM “just in case” than pushing it out to disk when the memory isn’t needed for anything else.**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

Comment: Standby doesn't slowdown the PC, it makes it **FASTER**. If you have slowdowns, they come from something else.

Comment: @Spik330 here is commandline tool to clean standby: http://forum.sysinternals.com/rammap-empty-standby-list_topic27297_post132769.html#132769

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I have 32gb of RAM and when I start to notice a major slowdown in processing and especially seeing multiple open internet pages literally freeze, I check the memory status and without fail the standby memory in the 25GB+ range.

After clearing standby memory using Microsoft santioned RAMMAP's clear standby memory option, the internet speeds up considerably.  You may ask yourself if there is no need to clear standby memory, why does Microsoft feel the need to tell you how to do so.  Too many of the so called experts who say that high standby memory is a good thing, are not quit the experts they pretend to be.  I they were, they would know that a lot of things in Windows don't work quite like Microsoft says they will.